# Django - How to assign a instance to a foreign key attribute

Tags: django, instance

I'm having a problem to assign an foreign key attribute to a new object. When I try to make that I get this error

> Cannot assign "(< ConceptType: Producto >,)": "Receipt.concept" must be
>   a "ConceptType" instance.

Well, this is the code in the view

```
if form.is_valid():
    receipt = form.save(commit=False)

    receipt.concept = ConceptType.objects.get(id=1),
```

this is for create a receipt using django-afip (https://gitlab.com/WhyNotHugo/django-afip)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your including of `,` makes your return value to `receipt.concept` a tuple which is not a `ConceptType` instance, that's why you should remove it.

It should just be:

```
receipt.concept = ConceptType.objects.get(id=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `,` after `receipt.concept = ConceptType.objects.get(id=1)` this line.

As Peter DeGlopper said in comment with `,` you receive tuple not single instance.

Comment: Specifically, the `,` makes it a tuple - it's equivalent to `receipt.concept = (ConceptType.object.get(id=1),)`.